# HTML5 What makes this technology what it is? The browser?

Tags: html

As a novice web developer, I ask; what makes html5 what it is? If we now do not need to have flash, java or other third party softwares to enhance our web browsing experience, does this imply that our new browsers must support these features? Is the new advancement in HTML(5) just contract to our browsers to supply them as native support features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the browser must support the features of HTML5 to implement and render them. Usually some browsers vendors like Mozilla, Google or Opera propose some new features, create some demos and then when it is broadly used it is implemented by others browsers or it goes to the w3c draft.

You can check the official draft at: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/.